# How to use the two Modal Class attribute in a Spring MVC Form in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

### New Registeration Form

**Step 1: UserLoginDTO.java**

```
private String userName;
private String password;
```

**Step 2: UserInfoDTO.java**

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
```

**Step 3 : Navigating to the Registration Form**

> http://localhost:8080/Demo/navigate/customerRegisterForm

**Controller :**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/navigate")
public class NavigationController {

    @RequestMapping("/customerRegisterForm")
    public String customerRegisterForm(Map modelmap) {
        System.out.println("Entering the New Customer Registarion Portal... ");
        UserInfoDTO infoDto = new UserInfoDTO();
        UserLoginDTO loginDto = new UserLoginDTO();
        modelmap.put("infoDto", infoDto);
        modelmap.put("loginDto", loginDto);
        return "customer/newCustomer";
    }

}
```

**Step 4 :  newCustomer.jsp**

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="loginDto">

<form:input path="userName"/>
<form:input path="password"/>
<form:input path="firstName"/>
<form:input path="lastName"/>

<input type="submit" value="Add Employee"/>


</form:form>
```

> NOTE: In Step 3, two model class are added into the **modelmap** and in step 4 **modelAttribute="loginDto"** is alone used. So the Below is error is thrown. **org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'firstName' of bean class [com.pharmacy.dto.UserLoginDTO]** I need to use the both model class in the view part

Comment: To have an answer, you should be more precise about what you want exactly, the step you are blocked with your code etc..

Comment: am new to this, i have edited the post, can you say it is clear or not.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class FormDto having your two existing model as attribute.

```
public class FormDto {
    private UserLoginDto loginDto;
    private UserInfoDto infoDto;

    //......add getter/setter 
}
```

Modify your controller to send FormDto as modelAttribute.

```
@RequestMapping("/customerRegisterForm") 
public String customerRegisterForm(Map modelmap) {
    System.out.println("Entering the New Customer Registarion Portal... ");
    FormDto formDto = new FormDto();
    modelmap.put("formDto", formDto);
    return "customer/newCustomer"; 
}
```

Finally, change your form attributes.

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="formDto">
    <form:input path="loginDto.userName"/>
    <form:input path="loginDto.password"/>
    <form:input path="infoDto.firstName"/>
    <form:input path="infoDto.lastName"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Employee"/>
</form:form>
```